# Use SAML Assertion as Authentication Header for Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, saml-2.0, bearer-token

I have Spring Boot(v2.7.10) project configured and running with SAML authentication, OAuth2 Resource and OAuth2 Authorization Client combined.

Here is my @EnableWebSecurity as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/login").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .saml2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt())
            .oauth2Login(
                    oauth2 -> oauth2.
                            defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
            )
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and()
            .logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            )
            .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
    ;
    return http.build();
}
```

Scenario:

> I can generate JWT Tokens through External IDP using OAuth2 Configurations.
> I can generate and validate SAML2 assertions through External IDP SAML2 Provider configurations.
> I have set of APIs that are protected using JWT Bearer Tokens using resource servers. e.g.
> Authorization: Bearer ey....

Question 1 - Is there a way in spring boot I can protect the APIs using SAML Assertion in request Header that can be verified by the External SAML IDP Provider configured in the application?
e.g. Sending request as
Authorization: SAML Base64EncodedSAML

Question 2 - If not, Can Spring be configured to expose APIs that take SAML Assertions and return JWT Access Token for an IDP.

Update:
I have tried SAML Bearer to exchange the Assertion for JWT Token as explained in some [link](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/guides/access-delegation/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile/) but I am looking for a solution in SpringBoot specifically.

Comment: I don't think I'm completely understanding what you are wanting to achieve. It's a bit unusual to be an OAuth 2.0 Client that wants to negotiate a login while also being a Resource Server that wants to accept access tokens from either itself or a different client. If "from itself", usually the JSESSIONID is sufficient, if "from a different client", usually those clients do their own negotiation. Can you provide some more detail on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @jzheaux What I try to achieve here is to reuse a SAML assertion. 

Scenario-1: Client-1 authenticates a user through SAML2 and wants to negotiate the SAML Assertion for an OAuth2 token from the IdP. i.e. SAML Grant Type as explained at https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/references/concepts/authorization/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile/


Scenario-2: Let say Client-1 authenticated a user using SAML2 and now wants to pass SAML token as authentication to Server-1 (Acting as Resource Server). 

I have accomplished Scenario-1. But I want to know if the second solution kind of accurate or not?